# How do I make my swift app send notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, notifications

I am having a problem with sending local notifications based on the local time of the users phone.

What I am trying to do, is make it so the user gets a notification a desired time before a fixed time.

The app seems to be working, and it is only the notifications that are not working.

Is there anything I am missing in the code for the functionality to work. I have made it so the app automatically asks for permission to send notifications the first time the user opens the app.

This is my current code.

**Content view:**

```
//  Created by Johannes With on 11/08/2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var isLoading = true
    @State private var daysSwitch: [Bool] = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "daysSwitch") as? [Bool] ?? Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
    @State private var olsalgetSwitch: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "olsalgetSwitch")
    @State private var vinmonopoletSwitch: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "vinmonopoletSwitch")
    @State private var timeInterval: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "timeInterval") != 0 ? UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "timeInterval") : 10

    let notify = NotificationHandler()
    let days = ["Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lørdag"]
    let timeIntervals = Array(stride(from: 10, to: 60, by: 10))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    if isLoading {
                        // Loading view
                        Image("Loader")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            .onAppear {
                                // Hide loading screen after 2 seconds
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                                    isLoading = false
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        // Main content view
                        Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "ToplogoWhite" : "ToplogoBlack")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 100)
                            .padding(.top, 40)
                        Text("Velg hvilket utsalg du vil bli varslet om")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.top, 0)
                        HStack {
                            Text("Ølsalget").bold()
                            Toggle("", isOn: $olsalgetSwitch)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Vinmonopolet").bold()
                            Toggle("", isOn: $vinmonopoletSwitch)
                        }
                        Divider()
                        Text("Velg hvilke dager du vil bli varslet på")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.headline)
                        ForEach(0..<days.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            HStack {
                                Text(days[index]).bold()
                                Toggle("", isOn: $daysSwitch[index])
                                    .disabled(!(olsalgetSwitch || vinmonopoletSwitch))
                            }
                        }
                        Divider()
                        Text("Velg når du vil bli varslet før salget stenger")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.headline)
                        Picker("Minutter før:", selection: $timeInterval) {
                            ForEach(timeIntervals, id: \.self) { interval in
                                Text("\(interval) minutter før").bold()
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Blir du ikke varslet? Klikk her!") {
                            notify.askPermission()
                        }
                        .bold()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Rakk du salget i dag takket være meg?").bold()
                            Text("Påspander meg en øl! Vipps: #822266").bold()
                        }
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: daysSwitch) { _ in saveSettings() }
                .onChange(of: olsalgetSwitch) { _ in saveSettings() }
                .onChange(of: vinmonopoletSwitch) { _ in saveSettings() }
                .onChange(of: timeInterval) { _ in saveSettings() }
            }
            .onAppear {
                notify.askPermission() // Automatically ask for permission
                scheduleNotifications() // Schedule notifications
            }
        }
    }

    private func saveSettings() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(daysSwitch, forKey: "daysSwitch")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(olsalgetSwitch, forKey: "olsalgetSwitch")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(vinmonopoletSwitch, forKey: "vinmonopoletSwitch")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(timeInterval, forKey: "timeInterval")
        scheduleNotifications() // Schedule notifications after saving settings
    }

    func scheduleNotifications() {
        // The logic for scheduling notifications based on the selected options
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Notifications handler:**

```
//  Created by Johannes Eikrem With on 11/08/2023.
//

import UserNotifications

class NotificationHandler {
    func askPermission() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                print("Access granted!")
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    func scheduleNotification(for day: String, minutesBefore: Int, deadlineHour: Int, title: String, body: String) {
        // Create date components for the specified day and time
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = deadlineHour
        dateComponents.minute = -(minutesBefore)

        // Set the weekday based on the specified day
        switch day {
        case "Mandag": dateComponents.weekday = 2
        case "Tirsdag": dateComponents.weekday = 3
        case "Onsdag": dateComponents.weekday = 4
        case "Torsdag": dateComponents.weekday = 5
        case "Fredag": dateComponents.weekday = 6
        case "Lørdag": dateComponents.weekday = 7
        default: return
        }

        // Create a trigger with the date components
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        // Create the content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.badge = 1

        // Create the request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Add the request to the notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to your question, but hard-coding the day names and passing a string day name into `scheduleNotification` is a bad idea. Make a Weekday enum that encapsulates this.

Comment: FYI `if let error = error` can also be written as `if let error` and print the error not it’s localized description

Comment: You were supposed to edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76884768/push-notifications-in-swift-ios-app-not-working) instead of posting this new one. Please delete one of your two questions.

Comment: You call always `scheduleNotifications` (with trailing `s`) which does nothing. You need to call `notify.scheduleNotification(…` with the appropriate parameters to send a notification. Side notes: You ask for permission but you ignore the result. Check the status before sending a notification. And why do you save always **all** settings even if only one value changes? And never use `setValue(_:forKey:)` in `UserDefaults` unless you mean KVC (you don't). Use  generic `set(_:forKey:)`.